# code completion suggestions for Android layout xml not working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

The code completion suggestions for Android Layout XML is not working in Juno.

When editing a layout xml file, no suggestions pop up and hitting Control-Space just beeps.

This used to work before I upgraded to Juno.

Eclipse' Installation Details says I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820, and ADT 21.1.0v201302060044-569685.

I'm using a mac.

Help | Check for Updates says there are no updates.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - the manifest file needed to have as the first line in the file -
    < ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Prior versions did not require this !

Comment: the post didn't include the line --

Comment: Actually this fixed it for one xml file but not for others.  I see no obvious difference between files that work and ones that don't.  I'll update if/when I find more info.

Answer (score 0):

My prior solution is not correct.  I stumbled on the solution today.

If the xml file is read only, then code completion does not work.
Make the file read/write and then code completion works.

This is not the behavior of the previous ADT.
Code completion used to work even for read only files, and if you saved a change the file was changed to read/write.

This BUG may only apply to Mac OSX, because I checked with someone using Windows and they do not have this BUG.